# Remove # from anchor in url

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a button on my website with this code:

```js
// set a short timeout before taking action
// so as to allow hash to be set
setTimeout(() => {
  // uses HTML5 history API to manipulate the location bar
  history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
}, 500); // 5 millisecond timeout in this case
```

```css
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1020px) {
  button {
    font-size: 15px!important;
    animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes glow {
    from {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 15px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498;
    }
    to {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498, 0 0 55px #00f498;
    }
  }
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  background: #000000;
  color: #00F498;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Rubik";
  font-weight: 900;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00F498, 0 0 25px #00BCAA, 0 0 50px #00F498;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

button span {
  position: absolute;
}

button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

button span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  right: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}

button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.17s;
}

button span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.52s;
}

button:active {
  background: #00F498;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00F498, #00BCAA);
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #00F498, 0 0 8px #00BCAA, 0 0 8px #00F498;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

button:active span:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) {
  transition: none;
  transition-delay: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik">
<a href="#mercadoaudiovisual" target="_top">
  <div>
    <button id="comeceagora">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span> Comece Agora!
    </button>
  </div>
</a>
```

I would like to remove the hash from the url anchor, but I have tried several ways and none have worked.

The last code I tried was this one:

```
<!-- F’in sweet Webflow Hacks -->
<script>
// set a short timeout before taking action
// so as to allow hash to be set
setTimeout(()=>{
  // uses HTML5 history API to manipulate the location bar
  history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
}, 5); // 5 millisecond timeout in this case
</script>
```

The site was built in a site builder called Zyro, I have the possibility to use `Javascript`, `html` and `css` and I have access to the `<head>`, but I believe the scripts don't work because I don't have direct access to the `<body>` of the site.

The button has been added to an embed code element.

The website link is this: https://bldgprod.com.br/

UPDATE:

I don't know if I formulated my question correctly, but I want the click on the button not to change the page url, because if a person wants to share the link with someone else, the link will be "contaminated".

Comment: A note about the idea of "replacing the URL": unless you're also storing the _page state_ when you're replacing history points, leave the nav history alone. Nothing worse than a site that violates how the history should intuitively work.

Comment: I think you didn't check the console for any potential errors as you have the following error `Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://bldgprod.com.br/nullsrcdoc' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://bldgprod.com.br'` which should make things more clear.

Comment: So, I'm really new to programming, so I don't understand how things work so well yet, that's why I used this script, it was the only one I found with an explanatory video.

What would be the best way to do what I would like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: This tip will help me a lot, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

I don't know if I formulated my question correctly, but I want the click on the button not to change the page url, because if a person wants to share the link with someone else, the link will be "contaminated".

Answer (score 0):

First off, you HTML structure is wrong.
You can't put `div` inside `a` tag, because `div` is a block level element, while `a` is an inline level element.

Block level elements can hold both other block level elements as well inline level elements inside of them, while inline level elements can only hold other inline level elements inside of them.

Other then that, what is the reason you want to remove # from href tag in your `a` tag ? :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, this will help me a lot in other situations. I'm a beginner and self-taught, so I still make some basic mistakes.

As for #, I don't know if I formulated my question correctly, but I want the click on the button not to change the page url, because if a person wants to share the link with someone else, the link will be "contaminated".

Comment: I highly recommend you go to Udemy and look up courses from Maximillian Shwarzmuller. He has courses on HTML, CSS, JS and JavaScript frameworks, he is AMAZING. Look at all his courses, learn it, and you will be crazy advanced.

Comment: One more tip, if you use incognito mode to go to Udemy, you will have all courses discounted like 86%.

Comment: Great! I will look and study as soon as possible. Thanks a lot for the tips.